# Quick Sort Algorithm - Median of Three

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I have the following quicksort algorithm which uses the leftmost as a pivot which is working perfectly well:

```
public static void QuickSortLeft(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    int left = start;
    int right = end;

    int pivot = array[start];

    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (array[left] < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }

        while (array[right] > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        if (left <= right)
        {
            swap(array,left, right);

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    // Recursive calls
    if (start < right)
    {
        QuickSortLeft(array, start, right);
    }

    if (left < end)
    {
        QuickSortLeft(array, left, end);
    }
}
```

Now I tried to do the Median of Three optimisation on the above my taking the median of the first, last and middle position and use the median as pivot as below, however I am getting a StackOverflow exception

```
public static void QuickSortMedian(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    int left = start;
    int right = end;

    int pivot = (array[start] + array[(start + (end - start)) / 2] + array[end]) / 2;

    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (array[left] < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }

        while (array[right] > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        if (left <= right)
        {
            swap(array, left, right);

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    // Recursive calls
    if (start < right)
    {
        QuickSortMedian(array, start, right);
    }

    if (left < end)
    {
        QuickSortMedian(array, left, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are taking average (or some biased variation of it...), not median. median has to be one of the three elements, your doesn't have to.

Comment: You add three values to form the pivot but only divide by two.

Comment: `(start + (end - start)) / 2 == end / 2`! It should simply be `(start + end) / 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calculating the average (but incorrectly - it should be `/3`, not `/2`), not the median.

You should pick the middle element of the three.

Something like: (pseudo-code)

```
sort(left, mid, right)
pick mid
```

With your current code, it's likely to end up with a value larger than everything else, so you can possibly end up partitioning off 0 elements to the right, just recursing on the same data towards the left repeatedly.

Comment: (1) It still won't be median - it will be average. (2) It still does not explain stackoverflow, only poor performance.

Comment: yes like @amit said, I still get Stack Overflow exception

Comment: @Dukeling thank you now I understand better. So I have to find the median of the three and then swap the first pos with the median?

Comment: @rikket Yes, you could swap the first position with the median, but it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Usually the choice of the center element `pivot = array[(start + end) / 2]` is good enough. Doing additional calculations adds a lot of additional array accesses and can actually slow down the sort. Picking the center element has the advantage to perform well on pre-sorted arrays.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes True, but median-of-three is a well-known pivot choice for quick-sort.

Comment: Thank you @Dukeling I sorted the array, and used the median as pivot and the algorithm works perfectly. 
I was confusing median with mean!

Answer (score -2):

This will give you the median:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Median<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source");
        }
        var sortedValues = source.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();
        if (sortedValues.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
        }
        var midpoint = (sortedValues.Count/2);
        return sortedValues[midpoint];
    }
}
```